# The topological property of $f(\Omega)$, where $f$ is a nonwhere vanishing holomorphic function and $\Omega$ is simply-connected.

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, logarithms, connectedness

A classic proposition in conmplex states as follows:

> If $f$ is a nonwhere vanishing holomorphic function in a simply connected region $\Omega$, then there exists a holomorphic function $g$ on $\Omega$ such that
> $$
> f(z)=e^{g(z)}.
> $$
> And the $g(z)$ can be denoted by $\log f(z)$, and determines a "branch" of that logarithm.

A proof can be found in MSE or Stein's *Complex Analysis*. But I wonder if we can say more about the range $f(\Omega)$. For example, in order to have the logrithm to be single-valued, it seems there at least exists a ray which starts from the origin such that it does not intersect with the range, i.e, $\exists \theta$, s.t.
$$
f(\Omega)\cap\{re^{i\theta}:r>0\}=\phi.
$$
Is this true and is there a rigid proof for this? Or, can we prove a stronger conclusion that $f(\Omega)$ is simply-connected in the given condition?

What we know for sure is that $f(\Omega)$ is a path-connected open set by the property of holomprphic functions. To simplify the problem, we may regard $\Omega$ as the unit disk.

Appreciate any help!

Comment: No, that’s definitely not true about the image. Let $\Omega=\Bbb{C}$, $f(z)=e^z$, which is the simplest possible example. Then, $f(\Omega)=\Bbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$, which has the property that for every ray, the intersection equals that ray, so it is non empty. Also, no $f(\Omega)$ is not simply-connected. There should be no stuff about rays because $g$ is a function defined on $\Omega$; we’re not trying to invert $f$ or anything.

Comment: In general, if $\Omega$ is simply connected but not the full plane, $f(\Omega)$ can be pretty much any domain that doesn't contain zero, while if we are on the full plane (and $f$ nonconstant), the image must be $\mathbb C - 0$ by Picard

Comment: More generally, if $U$ is a domain that doesn't contain $0$ and at least one more point, the uniformization theorem says that there is an analytic covering map (so, in particular, $f'$ doesn't vanish either) from the unit disc onto $U$, while if $U=\mathbb C^*$, one can take any analytic map that takes the unit disc to the full plane (eg map the unit disc onto $\Re z >-1$ with a Mobius transform and follow with $z^2$) and compose with the exponential to get an analytic map from $D$ onto $U$